# Textscan from end of line

Tags: matlab, file, textscan

I am trying to read a very heavy file. On each line I have some integers but the numbers of integers is not known. I just want to extract the last n items. I couldn't find the right syntax for doing this.

**Example:**

```
lineA='10 200 300 400 500';
lineB='300 400 500 550';
pA=textscan(lineA,'%u %u %u');
pB=textscan(lineB,'%u %u %u');
```

The results should be:

```
pA={[300]}    {[400]}    {[500]}
pB={[400]}    {[500]}    {[550]}
```

Currently I am not able to know the size of each line and I want to avoid having to. On this example I just read lines but in my actual script I read a file with 10e6 lines and I use the syntax `textscan(fid,format,10e6)`.

Comment: You could read an entire line and throw out everything but the last 3 of course. Reading from the end sounds difficult; perhaps it's possible to flip the line (character by character if necessary), read only the first three, and flip the extracted elements  back after reading?

Comment: What to do if you want the last 4 elements, but some lines only have 3 elements? A simple matrix-form will then no longer work, barring `nan` or fill-values.

Comment: In fact the lines have more than 3 elements but I only want the 3 last items of each line of the file.

Comment: Something along the lines of `L = fliplr( strsplit( lineX, ' ' ) ); L = fliplr( L(1:n) );` would work, but still requires reading the whole line into `lineX`.

Comment: `pA`, `pB`, etc is just for the illustration, right? You don't actually want 10e6 such variables?

Comment: @Wolfie it could be a solution but it works only line by line. My question is to know if a solution exists for reading the 10e6 lines in one time with `textscan(fid,format,N)` and N=10e6

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes it is just an example. My file has 10e6 lines. On each lines there is at the minimum 7 items (I don't know the maximum per line yet) and I only want to extract the 3 last items of each line.

Comment: I didn't ask that.

Comment: You'll have to do it a line at a time, e.g.:  lineA = fgets(fid); pA = sscanf(lineA, '%d'); pA = pA(end-1-n:end);

Comment: There are no way to read random specific parts of a full file without having a kind of _map_ of where your elements of interest are. You'll **have** to read the full file at some point (whether _line by line_, as a whole and then extract values, or preprocess the file so the values of interests are in known position). Any of these option will make you read the full file ... You just have to decide which option you prefer.